# Calling JavaScript method from Java Application

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome-extension

I have  Java Application(Applet having two buttons Stop and Start) when i click start button method in script  will be Executed.But my pure JavaScript code under Chrome Extension.When i click start button Click event method in JavaScript will be Executed.My question is Method calling fine but am unable to execute Chrome Extension code(message Passing).

This is my Java Application code.

```
       addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {  


            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { 
            Object val = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return set();");
            System.out.println("read java script value :" + val);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame.getComponent(0), "Hi Welcome To Start message Passing");

            System.out.println("Hi Welcome To Start message Passing");

        }
    });
```

My Chrome Extension code.

```
 function set() {
     chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
         greeting: "start"
     }, function (e) {
         window.alert("window alert method ");
         var backgroundPageConnection = chrome.runtime.connect({
             name: "panel"
         });
         backgroundPageConnection.postMessage({
             name: 'init',
             tabId: chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.tabId,
             inspectedEvents: default_selected
         });
     });
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Refactor your java code to pass by reference. Because pure javascript cannot understand your event situation for messsage passing.

Comment: But method calling fine...am struck at calling chrome extension code if it works that's fine for my requirement.

Comment: [java is always pass by value, there is no way to change java's behaviour to pass by reference](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm)

Comment: Java passes objects as references and those references are passed by value.

Comment: @nolines: Prehaps you can edit your answer to add more detail, and to show an example of *how* the code can be refactored? As it stands, your answer is more of a *vague suggestion*, than the high quality answers we hope to see on Stack Overflow.